What is the principal type for user assigned managed identity
While adding role assignments for storage account
I use user assigned managed identity
RoleAssignmentCreateOrUpdateContent roleData = new RoleAssignmentCreateOrUpdateContent(
   roleDefinitionId: new ResourceIdentifier(string.Concat("/subscriptions/", SubscriptionId, "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/", roleId)),
   principalId: PrincipalId);

But I am getting an error
ERROR: {"error":{"code":"PrincipalNotFound","message":"Principal xxx does not exist in the directory xxx. Check that you have the correct principal ID. If you are creating this principal and then immediately assigning a role, this error might be related to a replication delay. In this case, set the role assignment principalType property to a value, such as ServicePrincipal, User, or Group.  See https://aka.ms/docs-principaltype"}}       

It was suggested to add principaltype , what is the principal type for user assigned managed identity, user or group or serviceprincipal

For a user-assigned managed identity in Azure, the principal type you should use when creating a role assignment is "ServicePrincipal". So, you are trying to add role to user assigned managed identity under your storage account?

The API you are using seems to be for Service Principals and not for managed identity.
Asked copilot (free) and it gives me code using different API - Query: "Access Azure Storage using user defined managed identity - show me example C# code"
As an example, it basically used BlobServiceClient(Uri(storageAccountUrl), ManagedIdentityCredential) and blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(BlobContainerClient). Its not an answer, its a hint.

I am chaging the authentication method of a redis resource from managedidentity to access token
what should be added in redis config PreferredDataPersistenceAuthMethod.
Currently it is
"preferred-data-persistence-auth-method": "ManagedIdentity"
whst should be the "preferred-data-persistence-auth-method" while using connection string(access token) as a auth method

Managed Identities use service principals so you should set the principal type to "ServicePrincipal".

I am chaging the authentication method of a redis resource from managedidentity to access token
what should be added in redis config PreferredDataPersistenceAuthMethod.
Currently it is
"preferred-data-persistence-auth-method": "ManagedIdentity"
whst should be the "preferred-data-persistence-auth-method" while using connection string(access token) as a auth method
